# ANTLR4 generating improper java code

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to use [this grammar](https://github.com/rljacobson/FoxySheep) to parse Mathematica code. I used the gradle plugin to generate the java code. Two of the generated files contain improper java code like this :

```
private void LBARBRACKET_action(RuleContext _localctx, int actionIndex) {
    switch (actionIndex) {
    case 12:
        self.incrementBracketLevel(1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Maybe I could just remove all the "self." occurences but I don't want to do this. Has anyone faced the same issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced grammar is poorly constructed.  It uses an `import` statement to include the lexer wholesale.  Instead, just rely on ANTLR handling a proper split lexer/parser.

Rename (internally and externally) to `FoxySheepParser` and `FoxySheepLexer` 
and mark the grammar types:

```
  parser grammar FoxySheepParser ;
  lexer  grammar FoxySheepLexer  ;
```

FWIW, ANTLR internally separates the lexer from a combined grammar and then proceeds as if working with an ordinary split lexer/parser. Due to the complexity of the present lexer and how it was incorporated, this separation fails and, if any code is generated, the results cannot be certain to be reliable.

Finally, the grammar code generation defaults to Java. There are, however, native code statements present in the lexer that appear to be specific to Python. Either specify Python as the code generation target or replace the native statements with their Java equivalents (check the `java target/src` subdirectory).